# Need idea for general view mode differentiation

Tags: playframework

I am creating a web application that will have 2 view modes. One mode is just normal web site. The other view mode will be as a facebook app. In facebook, an app is shown in an iframe. In my app, I must be able to detect if the view is in facebook mode or standalone mode. I need to detect this because in facebook the screen is smaller (760px) so I need to select different CSS files but I also might change certain link targets, the general layout or certain controller behaviour. I want to deploy the whole application on one single server. I don't want to partition the application early. I do know how to separate both views physically on different nodes, i.e., by applying different application.conf files with a static parameter in it if this server is in facebook mode or not. The physical separation would mean 2 different configurations to test, with 2 different deployments, and I want to avoid that. So I am looking for a more "logical" separation.

I have the following ideas:

1.) adding a parameter to every request "GET /...?facebook=1" and extract that in a @Before method

the downside here is that I have to add the parameter to all subsequent links manually => tiresome and error prone

or is there a way to kind of "hack" the Router to do that when generating reverse routings?

2.) prefix the path with some context "GET /fb/..." and check it's presence in a @Before action

the downside here is that I will need to duplicate the routes and the show stopper seems to be that the reverse routing is ambiguous and I do not see a way to tell the router which route I want

again, is the a way to kind of hack into the Router to add the prefix on reverse routes?

3.) < your suggestion here, please ;) >

...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple solution: I'm going to alias the hostname of the target machines in the /etc/hosts of the Apache load balancer which then routes all requests for the facebook subdomain to the same cluster hosts as under normal view but is using the aliased names.

Then in my play controller I use a @Before action to check request.domain for the presence of the "facebooked" name aliases:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    static ThreadLocal<Boolean> facebook = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>();

    @Before
    static void globals() {
        facebook.set(request.domain.endsWith("-fb"));
        renderArgs.put("facebook", facebook.get());
    }

    protected static boolean isFacebook() {
        return facebook.get();
    }
}
```

2 different load balancers can now access one single play cluster. I've already build it and it works quite good so far.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best option, but you could create a main page that receives a parameter showing if they come from Facebook or not and store some flag in the Session of the user. Then create the paths to all css/js/links/etc your want to modify based on that parameter. Something like:

/public/static/${param}/file.ext

where ${param} could be FB or NFB and that will decide the paths.

Comment: That certainly sounds doable, thank you. I have found a solution which does not incorporate the play session. I kind of hesitate to start using the session object at all.